# How to stream audio to num py array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-sounddevice

I am trying to create a streaming app on flask but i can figure out how to make sound to num py array.I have tried:

```
import sounddevice as sd
   # seconds

def callback(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    if status:
        print(status)
    outdata[:] = indata

while True:
    x=sd.Stream.read(frames=1)
    print(x)
```

and using some other libbrarys coneccted to audio but i cinda dont understand nothing conected to their codes so it will be cool to tell me some info about the code
I know i should use sounddevice.Stream.read() but i cant figure out how

(sorry for bad grammar)

Answer (score 0):

Stream.read() returns two values.
Try this

```
narr,x=sd.Stream.read(frames=1)
print(narr)
```